My code not using HAL Abstraction outputs different USART values despite sharing the same ADC configuration as the working HAL code
The first main code followed by its adc configuration
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// stm specific headers
#include <stm32f4xx.h>
#include <stm32f411xe.h>

// custom headers
#include "adc.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "message_queue.h"
#include "math.h"



// STM32 specific values
// Change as needed. Refer to the message_queue.h file
#define SENSORTYPE VOLTAGE
#define SENSORDELAY 1000

// delay
void delay(int d){
    int i;
    for (; d>0 ;d--){
        for(i=0; i<2657; i++);
    }
}
//Reference: Hanapin sa EEE 158 files

//UART Handlers
UART_HandleTypeDef Huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef Huart2;


char* createJSONString(uint16_t value);

char* createJSONString(uint16_t value) {
    // Calculate the length of the JSON string
    size_t jsonLength = 50; // Initial length for JSON formatting

    // Allocate memory for the JSON string
    char* jsonString = (char*)malloc(jsonLength * sizeof(char));
    if (jsonString == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Construct the JSON string
    snprintf(jsonString, jsonLength, "{\"Voltage\":%d,\"value\":%d}", SENSORTYPE, value);

    return jsonString;
}

uint16_t volt = 0x0000;
uint16_t dequeued_value;
char msg[100];
int ADCVal[100]; //array to store ADC values
unsigned int max_v=0;
double VmaxD;
double VeffD;
int Veff;

int main(void) {
    usart2_init();
    ADC_init();

    // Initialize a queue
    Queue* queue = createQueue();

    /* Loop forever */
    while (1) {
        delay_ms(SENSORDELAY);

        // ADC related functionality
        ADC_enable();
        ADC_startconv();
        ADC_waitconv();
        //delay_ms(20);
        volt = ADC_GetVal();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            if (volt > 1986){ //1986 is ADC equivalent of 1.6V
                ADCVal[i]=volt;
            }
            else{
                ADCVal[i]=0;
            }
            //put delay here for stability
        }

        //Find max value in the array
        max_v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
            if (ADCVal[i]>max_v){
                max_v = ADCVal[i];
            }
            ADCVal[i]=0;
        }
        //Calculate actual voltage
        if (max_v !=0){
            VmaxD = max_v; //Set VmaxD to maximum sensor value
            VeffD = VmaxD/sqrt(2);
            Veff = (((VeffD - 420.76) / -90.24) * -210.2) + 210.2;  // Apply calibration and scaling to Veff (adc-actual)
        }
        else{
            Veff = 0;
        }
        dequeued_value = volt;

        // Message Queue related functionality
        enqueue(queue, volt);

        // Send to serial monitor
        if (!usart2_tx_is_busy() && !isEmpty(queue)) {
            DequeueResult result = dequeue(queue, &dequeued_value);

            if (result == DequeueResult_Success) {
                char* jsonDatapoint = createJSONString(dequeued_value);
                usart2_tx_send(jsonDatapoint, strlen(jsonDatapoint));
                // Free dynamically allocated memory
                free(jsonDatapoint);
            }
        }
    }
}


ADC configuration of first code
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stm32f4xx.h>
#include <stm32f411xe.h>
#include "adc.h"

// Pin PA1 ADC to STM
void ADC_init(void) {
    //enable adc clock
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 8);

    //prescaler = 4 naka 2 dati
    ADC->CCR |= (1 << 16);
    ADC->CCR &= ~(1 << 17);

    //configure ADC resolution to 12 bits
    ADC1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 25);
    ADC1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 24);

    //Configure to Scan mode //di nakascan mode sa hal version
    ADC1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 8);
    //Enable Interrupt for EOC
    ADC1->CR1 |= (1 << 5);
    //configure sampling time
    ADC1->SMPR2 &= ~(1 << 5);
    ADC1->SMPR2 &= ~(1 << 4);
    ADC1->SMPR2 |= (1 << 3);
    //end of conversion selection
    ADC1->CR2 &= ~(1 << 10);

    //DMA requests for single conversion mode
    ADC1->CR2 &= ~(1<<9);

    //configure data alignment (RIGHT)
    ADC1->CR2 &= ~(1 << 11);

    //total number of conversions in the channel conversion sequence 1
    ADC1->SQR1 &= ~(1 << 23);
    ADC1->SQR1 &= ~(1 << 22);
    ADC1->SQR1 &= ~(1 << 21);
    ADC1->SQR1 &= ~(1 << 20);

    //assign channel for first conversion
    ADC1->SQR3 |= (1 << 0);

    //cont conversion mode disabled
    ADC1->CR2 &= ~(1 << 1);
}

void ADC_enable(void) {
    ADC1->CR2 |= (1 << 0); //enable the adc
    delay_ms(1); // required to ensure adc stable
}

void ADC_startconv(void) {
    ADC1->CR2 |= (1 << 30);
}

void ADC_waitconv(void) {
    //wait for the end of conversion
    while (!((ADC1->SR) & (1 << 1))) {
        ;
    }
    delay_ms(20);
}

int ADC_GetVal(void) {
    return ADC1->DR; //read the value contained at the data register
}

void delay_ms(int delay) {
    int i;
    for (; delay > 0; delay--) {
        for (i = 0; i < 2657; i++)
            ;
    }
}


Code which outputs the correct values but is using HAL abstraction
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

uint16_t volt=0;
char msg[20];
int ADCVal[100]; //array to store ADC values
unsigned int max_v=0;
double VmaxD;
double VeffD;
int Veff;

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 20);

      //Based from Electropeak Arduino Code!
      volt= HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            if (volt > 1986){ //1986 is ADC equivalent of 1.6V
                ADCVal[i]=volt;
            }
            else{
                ADCVal[i]=0;
            }
            //put delay here for stability
        }
        //Find max value in the array
        max_v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
            if (ADCVal[i]>max_v){
                max_v = ADCVal[i];
            }
            ADCVal[i]=0;
        }
        //Calculate actual voltage
        if (max_v !=0){
            VmaxD = max_v; //Set VmaxD to maximum sensor value
            VeffD = VmaxD/sqrt(2);
            Veff = (((VeffD - 420.76) / -90.24) * -210.2) + 210.2;  // Apply calibration and scaling to Veff (adc-actual)
        }
        else{
            Veff = 0;
        }

      sprintf(msg, "Voltage: %hu \r\n", max_v);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      HAL_Delay(500);

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
  ADC_InjectionConfTypeDef sConfigInjected = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1; //done
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4; //done
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B; //done
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE; //done
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE; //done
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE; //TODO dunno how to disable this with stn registers
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START; //TODO external trigger conversion edge
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT; //done
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1; //done
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE; //done?? ADC1->CR2 &= ~(1<<9);
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV; //done??//enabled na   ADC1->CR1 |= (1 << 5); but not sure if tama
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configures for the selected ADC injected channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time
  */
  sConfigInjected.InjectedChannel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfigInjected.InjectedRank = 1;
  sConfigInjected.InjectedNbrOfConversion = 1;
  sConfigInjected.InjectedSamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  sConfigInjected.ExternalTrigInjecConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGINJECCONVEDGE_NONE;
  sConfigInjected.ExternalTrigInjecConv = ADC_INJECTED_SOFTWARE_START;
  sConfigInjected.AutoInjectedConv = DISABLE;
  sConfigInjected.InjectedDiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  sConfigInjected.InjectedOffset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_InjectedConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfigInjected) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA5 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */


The first code output ranges at around 25, while the HAL code outputs around 2000 which is the expected value. Is it a problem with how I configured the ADC or is it something else? I think I have correctly copied the HAL configuration to non-HAL configuration, but somehow, the output is still incorrect. BTW, I am displaying the output through PuTTY. Code 1 uses 57600 baudrate while the second uses 115200.

Your delay() function could well be getting optimised away by the compiler.

I forgot to comment out the delay() function. I'm using delay_ms(). Should I use systick instead?
void delay_ms(int delay) {
int i;
for (; delay > 0; delay--) {
for (i = 0; i < 2657; i++)
;
}
}

Any delay function based on loops like that is likely to be optimised away by the compiler, or not delay for however long you think it does. Use a proper delay like SysTick or a timer.

https://godbolt.org/z/av1vzdx1Y
